# Clearly organized list of typical function spaces, norms and their completions, with standardized notations?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm trying to learn about distributions theory. After quickly looking at multiple sources,

I'm seeing various functional spaces being mentionned such as $C^k$, $C^k_c$, $C^k_K$, $C^\infty$, $C^\infty_c$, $C^\infty_K$, $L^p$, $L^p_c$, $L^\infty$, $L^\infty_c$, $l^p$,..., bounded functions, probably others I haven't yet encoutered like Sobolev spaces.

I'm seeing various distances/norms/semi-norms such as :

$‖f‖_{C^k,p,K}=\left( \sum_{|\alpha|\leq k} ‖∂^\alpha f‖^p_{u,K} \right)^{1/p} $

$‖f‖_{C^k,p}=‖f‖_{C^k,p,U}$

$d_{C^\infty,p}(f,g)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} 2^{-n} \dfrac{‖f‖_{C^n,p,K_n}}{1+‖f‖_{C^n,p,K_n}}$

$‖f‖_{L^p}=(\int_U ‖f‖^p)^{1/p}$

probably others I'm missing.

Ive already tried to standardize those notations a little bit myself as they vary between sources. I am mostly interested in the case where input and ouput are two real vector spaces of finite dimension, not just the unidimensional case. Input often seems to be some open set U in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Is there any existing clearly organized, and brief, source that mentions all these classic spaces and their possible metrics, and some simple topological properties about them, like what their completion is, so that I can have a quick ref of which are Banach spaces and which are not? Proofs would be nice too.

Thank you

Comment: The issue, is that often many of those sources, just focus on one type of functional space and goes on studying all its properties, so its hard to just find a list of (space,metric) pairs and their simple properties without focusing on a deep study of each of them. Then when I want to recall and gather these properties its all spread out

Comment: I advise against searching for such thing. There are A LOT of different spaces and trying to understand all of them is very frustrating. To make things worse, the same spaces often can be defined in very different ways and every community adopts a different viewpoint. Finally, notation is a nightmare and often non-standard.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree its difficult,  its the traditional way to study each space and all its properties one after another. The problem is that you memorize things only along one path. If you need to use your memory to answer a question like "which spaces satisfy this, or which space dont satisfy this", It is usually hard to do because its not the way knowledge is organized in your memory. But its a bias, if I was good I should be able to think transversally about things...